# 7Zip extraction on linux is so slow

Tags: linux, windows, xenserver, xfs

Extracting 7zip with many small files on linux xfs, extraction speed is so slow.

**My Test System Environment.**

- System1 : 2vCore/4GB CentOS 6.5 64bit guest on XenServer.
- System2 : 2vCore/4GB Windows 2012 guest on XenServer.

**Large small files Creation Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100000}
do
    dd if=/dev/zero of=./dmp/dd$i.dmp bs=1K count=4
done
```

ok. I got 4KB files of 100,000 in dmp directory.
and then I formatted /testfs with xfs.

Test

```
Compression Time on System1 :
   # time 7za a dmp.7z ./dmp     --> real   0m27.518s
Extraction Time on System1: 
   # time 7za x dmp.7z -o/testfs --> real   9m5.420s
   - 7za use only single core.
   - Dirent system call use most of the CPU time.
Extraction Time on System2:
   - around 25s
   - 7za use multi-core.
```

**My Question**

1. Although system2 use multi-core and system1 use single-core, such a big different result is unreliable. I think. How can I explain this ?
2. If I use xfs on linux for extracting 7zip file, How can I speed up ? any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a *huge* variable here: IO. What do the storage systems of the two systems look like?

Comment: ok. Two systems share the same nfs storage repository that is abstracted by  hypervisor. thanks.

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem. 60 MB archive with small files takes minutes on Fedora and less than 1s on Windows. Some shit happens with p7zip on Linux.

Comment: And it is not related to file system. I have XFS, EXT4, with luks and without. Resut is the same. Considering that question is 4 years old, I have to switch to another archiving tool.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and the fix was to upgrade 7z. On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the `7z` you get from `apt install` is from 2016. Instead, go download the latest version from the [official website](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

For the same archive with 60k small files on the same server, I went from 8 minutes to 6 seconds(!).

Comment: The OP specifically specified CentOS vs. Windows. Giving an Ubuntu solution may or may not work.

Comment: @doneal24 From the question title and its tags I understand it to be about Linux in general and that CentOS was only used as an example.

Comment: This gives a 20x speed up in Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Ops are using centos, why are u posting a ubuntu solution? DOes this works on centos??

Comment: @NicholasJela I already answered that question in another comment. I don’t know if it works on CentOS, but it’s quite simple to test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get Nautilus and Archive Manager (file-roller) in Ubuntu 22.04 to update to use 7-Zip 22.01:

Download https://7-zip.org/a/7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz

In the Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) copy and paste the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
sudo 7z e 7z2201-linux-x64.tar.xz 7z2201-linux-x64.tar
sudo 7z e -o/usr/lib/p7zip -y 7z2201-linux-x64.tar 7zz 7zzs
sudo echo exec /usr/lib/p7zip/7zz '"$@"' > 7z
sudo mv 7z /bin/7z
sudo chmod ugo+rx /usr/lib/p7zip/7zz /usr/lib/p7zip/7zzs /bin/7z
```